# Secury Benefits of PHP PDO vs mysql_*()

Tags: php, pdo

Are there any security benefits of using PHP PDO instead of the mysql_connect(), etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no security benefit to PDO vs the MySQL extension (except for what Murphy's law has taught us, which applies to both). Both will render input safe by escaping the same characters.

However, PDO has other advantages:

- Support for prepared statements;
- Object-oriented interface;
- Data access abstraction; and
- Produces cleaner code because you can escape multiple values at once

These are generally considered as the most important.

Answer (score 3):

No need even to bindParam, just do

```
$stmt = $pdoConnection->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = :baz');
$stmt->execute(array(':baz' => 1));
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
}
```

That easy.

Comment: I typically use the array binding method too. Important to remember though that doing it this way passes all array values into PDO as string types.  If you absolutely need an input value to be an int or boolean, you should use `bindParam` with the appropriate data type constant `PDO::PARAM_INT, PDO::PARAM_BOOL` etc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using `bindParam()` method instead of string concatenation with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

It's much easier to remember to `bindParam()` outside data than it is to remember to escape every value yourself with `mysql_*`.

In addition, PDO is just much nicer to work with.

Comment: Well, to be fair the newer `mysqli` extension supports prepared queries ala `bindParam`. Not `mysql_*` though mind you.